# How to select entities using ListStringProperty in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to do two operation with use ListStringProperty how to do selection by one and selection by all?

Let me explain I have such data:

```
Something(db.Model):
  tags: StringListProperty()

Something(tag = ['black', 'high']).put()
Something(tag = ['black', 'low']).put()
Something(tag = ['white', 'high']).put()
Something(tag = ['white', 'low']).put()
```

I want to select all `Something` with 'high' or 'black' - how to do it with query?

I want to select all `Something` with 'high' and 'black' - how to do it with query?

Something.all().filter('tag', 'black').filter('tag', 'high') for and?

How to do Something.all().filter('tag', 'black') + Something.all().filter('tag', 'high')?

Answer (score 1):

AND: Something.all().filter('tag =', 'black').filter('tag =', 'high')

OR: Something.all().filter('tag IN', ['black', 'high'])

Answer (score 0):

I don't think and is possible, OR is definitely possible. Just do something like Something.all().filter('tag', 'black').filter('tag', 'high'), read more here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries

If your list only contains few elements and the AND operator only for few elements, you can do  trick by appending the elements. For example, if your AND operation only for 2 elements, you can store "blackhigh", "blacklow", "whitehigh", "whitelow", etc, basically store nCk element where K is the number of operand for AND operator